# Probability President Percent will be reelected when he's supported by 8.4-8.5% of the population, and they're evenly distributed in the country

Tags: probability

Original Question:

Mathland has a population fo 997,997 people. It's divided into provinces, with each being made up of the same number of counties, the counties being made up of the same number of towns, and each town having the same population.

If a new person enters a town, someone else must leave, and vice versa. However, only followers of the current president are allowed to move between towns, and they make up around 8.4-8.5% of the total population.

Elections work with each town electing a mayor by majority, the mayors electing a county rep by majority, the county reps electing a province governer by majority, and the province governers electing a president.

Given this information, can President Percent be reelected without committing election fraud?

So far, I know how many people support President Percent (Between 83831 and 84829), the number of residents in a town by looking at the prime factors (it can be 7,11,13, or 997 but my teacher told me it works out regardless of what you set as the population for a town, so I'm just using 997 which works out to 1001 towns existing)

If a town has 997 people, 499 would have to vote for Percent, and 501 towns would have to do this. Since that would mean 249999 people are needed, I'm not sure it's possible for percent to win at all with the percent of the population that supports him, or if I'm approaching the problem correctly.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You do not need 501 towns to vote for the president. Just enough to win enough mayors to win enough county reps to win enough province governors.  $83831$ is not quite enough but then it is less than $8.4\%$ of $997997$

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  If only loyal supporters are allowed to switch towns and the number of people in a town must be conserved, then no matter what the loyal supports do they don't change their percentage within a town.  Did you maybe mean something like "a loyal supporter can freely move from $A$ to $B$ and they may select any resident of $B$ with whom to switch"?  Or am I misunderstanding the mechanism?

Comment: @lulu - I think that you can assume your second point, and essentially the president's supporters can distribute themselves however they wish with opponents involuntarily replacing them elsewhere.

Comment: @Henry  That's my best guess as well.

Comment: "Someone else must leave", but "only followers [...] are allowed to move between towns", that means followers can force non-followers out of the country?

Comment: @peterwhy  That's the only reading that makes sense.   I think. If the only allowed move is for one follower to switch with another, then there is no electoral point to moving.

Comment: Regardless of any gerrymandering in any level, it's not possible if there are $7$ provinces, each with $11$ counties, each with $12961$ towns, each with the same population of $1$.

Comment: For the moving around bit, only followers are allowed to move freely. They can force nonfollowers to move if they choose to settle in another town, but the nonfollowers can't move freely between towns.